# Activtii/OSGI, TaskListener not added as Activiti service to delegate cache

Tags: osgi, task, listener, activiti

Hello I have a problem with osgi on servicemix. 
It cannot bind or unbind service to delegate cache, when using **TaskListener** interface. **JavaDelegate** works fine in osgi with delegate expression.

Could this solution solve the problem or is there something else needed with BlueprintContextELResolver? Because the blueprint with the

```
service ref="something" interface="org.activiti.engine.delegate.TaskListener"/>

package org.activiti.osgi.blueprint;



/**
 * @see org.activiti.spring.ApplicationContextElResolver
 */
public class BlueprintELResolver extends ELResolver {

    private Map<String, JavaDelegate> delegateMap = new HashMap<String, JavaDelegate>();
    private Map<String, TaskListener> taskListenerMap = new HashMap<String, TaskListener>();
    private Map<String, ActivityBehavior> activityBehaviourMap = new HashMap<String, ActivityBehavior>();

    public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        if (base == null) {
            // according to javadoc, can only be a String
            String key = (String) property;
            LOGGER.info("Show string key: {}", key);
            LOGGER.info("Show property: {}", property);
            for (String name : delegateMap.keySet()) {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    LOGGER.info("Show property JavaDelegate: {}", name);
                    context.setPropertyResolved(true);
                    return delegateMap.get(name);
                }
            }
            for (String name : taskListenerMap.keySet()) {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    LOGGER.info("Show property TaskListener: {}", name);
                    context.setPropertyResolved(true);
                    return taskListenerMap.get(name);
                }
            }
            for (String name : activityBehaviourMap.keySet()) {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    context.setPropertyResolved(true);
                    return activityBehaviourMap.get(name);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void bindService(JavaDelegate delegate, Map props) {
    String name = (String) props.get("osgi.service.blueprint.compname");
    delegateMap.put(name, delegate);
    LOGGER.info("added Activiti service to delegate cache {}", name);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void unbindService(JavaDelegate delegate, Map props) {
        String name = (String) props.get("osgi.service.blueprint.compname");
    if(delegateMap.containsKey(name)) {
        delegateMap.remove(name);
    }
    LOGGER.info("removed Activiti service from delegate cache {}", name);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void bindTaskListenerService(TaskListener delegate, Map props) {
    String name = (String) props.get("osgi.service.blueprint.compname");
    taskListenerMap.put(name, delegate);
    LOGGER.info("added Activiti service to delegate cache {}", name);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void unbindTaskListenerService(TaskListener delegate, Map props) {
        String name = (String) props.get("osgi.service.blueprint.compname");
    if(taskListenerMap.containsKey(name)) {
        taskListenerMap.remove(name);
    }
    LOGGER.info("removed Activiti service from delegate cache {}", name);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void bindActivityBehaviourService(ActivityBehavior delegate, Map props) {
        String name = (String) props.get("osgi.service.blueprint.compname");
        activityBehaviourMap.put(name, delegate);
        LOGGER.info("added Activiti service to activity behaviour cache {}", name);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void unbindActivityBehaviourService(ActivityBehavior delegate, Map props) {
        String name = (String) props.get("osgi.service.blueprint.compname");
        if(activityBehaviourMap.containsKey(name)) {
            activityBehaviourMap.remove(name);
        }
        LOGGER.info("removed Activiti service from activity behaviour cache {}", name);
    }

    public boolean isReadOnly(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        return true;
    }

    public void setValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property,
        Object value) {
    }

    public Class<?> getCommonPropertyType(ELContext context, Object arg) {
        return Object.class;
    }

    public Iterator<FeatureDescriptor> getFeatureDescriptors(ELContext context,
        Object arg) {
        return null;
    }

    public Class<?> getType(ELContext context, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        return Object.class;
    }
}
```

After this I still get:

> Exception while invoking TaskListener: Unknown property used in
>   expression:  ${expression}

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem where the El resolver was not being fully initiated.

I resolved the problem by overloading the BlueprintExpressionManager when loading the configuration:

```
    public class BlueprintExpressionManagerReordered extends ExpressionManager
{
    @Override
    protected ELResolver createElResolver(VariableScope variableScope){
        CompositeELResolver elResolver = new CompositeELResolver();
        elResolver.add(new VariableScopeElResolver(variableScope));
        elResolver.add(new ArrayELResolver());
        elResolver.add(new ListELResolver());
        elResolver.add(new MapELResolver());
        if (_blueprintContextELResolver != null) {
            elResolver.add(_blueprintContextELResolver);
        }
        elResolver.add(_blueprintELResolver);
        elResolver.add(new BeanELResolver());

        return elResolver;
    }
}
```

It is called during init of the process engine configuration:

```
public class ProcessEngineFactoryWithELResolverReordered extends ProcessEngineFactoryWithELResolver
{
    private BlueprintELResolver _blueprintELResolver;
    private BlueprintContextELResolver _blueprintContextELResolver;

    public void init() throws Exception
    {
        super.init();
        ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl configImpl = (ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl)getProcessEngineConfiguration();
        final BlueprintExpressionManagerReordered mgr = new BlueprintExpressionManagerReordered();
        configImpl.setExpressionManager(mgr);
        if (configImpl.getActivityBehaviorFactory() instanceof DefaultActivityBehaviorFactory) {
            ((DefaultActivityBehaviorFactory)configImpl.getActivityBehaviorFactory()).setExpressionManager(mgr);
        }
        if (configImpl.getListenerFactory() instanceof DefaultListenerFactory) {
            ((DefaultListenerFactory)configImpl.getListenerFactory()).setExpressionManager(mgr);
        }
    }
```

And referenced in my context.xml

```
    <bean id="processEngineFactory"
      class="com.bp3.oss.custom.ProcessEngineFactoryWithELResolverReordered"
      init-method="init"
      destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="processEngineConfiguration"
              ref="configuration"/>
    <property name="bundle" ref="blueprintBundle"/>
    <property name="blueprintELResolver"
              ref="blueprintELResolver"/>
    <property name="blueprintContextELResolver" ref="blueprintContextELResolver"/>
</bean>
```

Not sure if this will help, but may give you something to go after.